# Prevent Julia from automatically converting the type of a 1D matrix slice

Tags: types, julia, slice

```
alpha = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
alpha[:, 1] # Type is Array{Int64, 1}
alpha[:, 1:2] # Type is Array{In64, 2}
```

I just want to prevent the automatic type conversion, but I am having an amazingly hard time figuring out how to do this.  Yeah, I could just go `alpha[:, 1]''`, but I want to prevent the memory reallocation.  There is `vec()` for going the other direction (1xn matrix) but I can't find a function for keeping a (nx1) matrix a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use a range of length 1 instead of just an index

Instead of simply specifying the index (`Int64`) of the desired column, specify a range (`UnitRange{Int64}`) of *length 1*: `1:1`.

That will trick Julia into preserving the 2D-array type (`Array{Int64,2}`) instead of returning a vector (`Array{Int64,1}`).

**Edit**: the developers discussed this topic [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/231) (thanks to [Colin for pointing me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153924/prevent-julia-from-automatically-converting-the-type-of-a-1d-matrix-slice/27154218#comment42855894_27154218)).

```
julia> alpha = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
2x3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6

julia> alpha[:,1]            # nope
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4    

julia> alpha[:,1:1]          # yep
2x1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 4
```

Comment: Thanks, very handy.  How did you know to do this?  Was it in the documentation somewhere or did you just figure it out messing around?

Comment: @Nick Messing around. Still getting to grips with Julia myself `:)` It may be mentioned somewhere in the documentation, though. I will report back here once I get through it all.

Comment: Haha, yeah.  I've been having to experiment with @code_lowered to figure out what's going on half the time, but I still haven't gotten used to understanding the ASTs

Comment: so oddly enough `alpha[:, 1]''` generates a lot less assembly than `alpha[:, 1:1]` as given by `@code_native`.  Hard to tell which is faster without benchmarking I suppose...

Comment: The developer discussion on this topic is [here (issue #231)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/231). The trick with ranges is indirectly mentioned there. I don't think it is in the docs (from memory).