# How can I write code to work with 1D matrices in Julia?

Tags: julia

Consider the following code

```
function test(m,B)
    @show typeof(B)
    all_u = rand(m,10)
    one_u = all_u[:,1]
    B*one_u
end
# Works
@show test(3, [1 1 1; 2 2 2])
# Works
@show test(2, [1 1; 2 2])
# Fails
@show test(1, [1; 2])
```

The last line fails with

```
`*` has no method matching *(::Array{Int64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1})
```

because `B` is now a 1-D vector (which is not OK), and so is `one_u` (which is always the case, and doesn't cause issues).

How can I write `test(m,B)` to handle the `m==1` case that doesn't require actually special casing it for `m==1` (i.e. using an `if`)? I know that for `m==1` case I could actually write another method to dispatch on the fact that `B` is a `Vector` but that seems terribly wasteful.

Comment: Your question reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153924/prevent-julia-from-automatically-converting-the-type-of-a-1d-matrix-slice... Would `one_u = all_u[:,1:1]` not do the trick?

Comment: If you have two 1d Arrays and you are looking for the scalar product then I use the `dot` function (as in `dot(B, one_u)`).

Comment: Jubobs that does look very similar, I will investigate. spencerlyon2 I don't know that I have two 1D arrays, as B is sometimes a matrix, sometimes a vector/1D matrix - thats the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from [your follow-up comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242576/how-can-i-write-code-to-work-with-1d-matrices-in-julia/30244935#comment48587531_30242576):

> `B` is sometimes a matrix, sometimes a vector/1D matrix - that's the problem.

You can convert a vector to a 2D array with the "slicing" operation `[:;:]`. In other words, if `B` has type `Array{T,1}`, then `B[:,:]` has type `Array{T,2}`:

```
julia> B = [1; 2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> typeof(B[:, :])
Array{Int64,2}
```

On the other hand, if `B` already has type `Array{T,2}`, then `[:;:]` is a no-op:

```
julia> B = [1 1; 2 2]
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  2

julia> typeof(B[:, :])
Array{Int64,2}

julia> B[:, :] == B
true
```

Therefore, in order to accommodate your function definition for the case `m==1` (i.e. convert `B` to a 2D array when needed), you can simply substitute `B[:,:]*one_u` for `B*one_u`:

```
julia> function test(m, B)
           @show typeof(B)
           all_u = rand(m, 10)
           one_u = all_u[:, 1]
           B[:, :] * one_u
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @show test(3, [1 1 1; 2 2 2])
typeof(B) => Array{Int64,2}
test(3,[1 1 1;2 2 2]) => [1.4490640717303116,2.898128143460623]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.44906
 2.89813

julia> @show test(2, [1 1; 2 2])
typeof(B) => Array{Int64,2}
test(2,[1 1;2 2]) => [0.9245851832116978,1.8491703664233956]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.924585
 1.84917 

julia> @show test(1, [1; 2])
typeof(B) => Array{Int64,1}
test(1,[1,2]) => [0.04497125985152639,0.08994251970305278]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0449713
 0.0899425
```